# how to get number of cars on a lane in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am using **anyLogic** simulator to simulate my traffic model. How can I get the **current number** of cars waiting on **any** of the signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function int nCars(boolean isOnForwardSide) for road will give you the number of cars on this road in the direction specified. Depending on the particular layout function may be useful. In addition, it should be noted that .nCars function gives the number of cars, which will include cars that are stopped at the end, as well as cars moving at any speed along the way. Depending on how one consider "waiting on" a traffic signal, additional processing/calculation may be needed. This would probably apply for the solution in the first answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no direct function to retrieve how many cars are waiting in front of a traffic signal in AnyLogic.

You will have to do this manually:

Use two stop lines, one at the beginning of the area you want to monitor and the one attached to your traffic light. 
Use the *Actions/On car passed* code field of the respective stop line to add (at the first stop line) and remove (at the traffic light stop line) the car from a collection. To do so use the code `carCollection.add(car)` and `carCollection.remove(car)`, assuming your collection is named *carCollection*.
To retrieve the number of cars currently existing in the monitored street area, just retrieve `carCollection.size()`.